# Angular $cookies are empty only when run under protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, restangular, angular-cookies

I have an Angular/Restangular application that appends a **X-CSRFToken** header to all POST requests to a backend REST API. The value of the header is extracted from **$cookies.csrftoken**. This is necessary because of a behaviour of the Django backend with SessionAuthentication - it requires this header for POST requests. CORS is configured between the domains of the frontend and backend.

This works nicely in a normal browser session in either Chrome or Firefox.

When running via Webdriver and Protractor, the csrftoken cookie is indeed present and sent, but **$cookies** is empty to Angular and thus so is X-CSRFToken. I can clearly see this happen with print debug and in debugger during the Firefox instance spawned by webdriver.

This **only** happens when running the test suite via protractor. I can't replicate the empty $cookies any other way. I'm also surprised that behaviour can be so different under the test framework.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It's because protractor was opening a browser under localhost which has stricter CORS security. All my manual tests just happened to access the app via a local IP address other than localhost.